# Writing back a function through Response.Write()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to return a javascript function using response.write in an aspx page. The problem is that the function i am returning has lots of quotes and they are conflicting with the repsonse.write syntax. Here is a sample code:

```
Response.Write("        If hello.StartsWith("H", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) OrElse hello.StartsWith("W", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then")
```

This is giving me a problem as the quotes inside are cutting off the response early. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just put it in the .aspx markup.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes? Like: `Response.Write(" If hello.StartsWith(\"H\", ...` or you could even use single quote to wrap the internal function: `Response.Write('If hello.StartsWith("H", ... Then');`

Comment: what exactly is the aspx markup? I need this response to be written within a function so i cannot exactly use the code blocks if thats what you mean

Comment: @JohnBaum That is VB code you are response.writing. That will not be able to run in a browser. You need to rewrite that as JavaScript and then you can use rick's answer below (using a combination of single and double quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace double qoute " with single qoute ' in your javascript as in javascript both " and ' do the same and c# will not object single qoute but RegisterClientScriptBlock could be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach, [`RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) is better, but this will work given you are emitting JavaScript not VB.NET code:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('test');</script>")
```

*Note: If you need to escape strings do a simple search in Google or this site and you will be fine.*

Comment: i dont understand how this gets around the double quote issue

Comment: It doesn't, do some searching, that question is answered on this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use chr(34) for quote as shown below to create a string of js function: 

sJavaScript = sJavaScript & vbTab & vbTab & "if(TheForm."
sJavaScript = sJavaScript & "FieldName" & ".value == " & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
sJavaScript = sJavaScript & ")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "{" & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function that you are outputting is javascript, then one approach is to use single quotes instead.  From javascript's perspective, single quotes and double quotes are more or less interchangable for string literals (though I am sure that there are cases where this isn't true- I just don't know javascript well enough to say what they are).

```
Response.Write("        If hello.StartsWith('H', ...
```